# Fade/Scale page

Tags: html, css, animation

I use the following animation to fade/scale a div that acts as an overlay over a page (see overlay class).

```
@keyframes fadeInScale {
    0%{
        opacity:0;
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    100%{
        opacity:1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeOutScale {
    0%{
        opacity:1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100%{
        opacity:0;
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 500;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fade-scale-in {
    display: block;
    animation: fadeInScale 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}

.fade-scale-out {
    display: block;
    animation: fadeOutScale 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}
```

I basically add the classes `fade-scale-in` (when it shows up) and `fade-scale-out` (when its removed from the page) to the div with class `overlay`. The problem is the `fadeOutScale` animation causes the div to disappear to the top of the original page (that it is overlayed on) not to the spot where the user is currently at on the original page. That happens only when I scroll down the overlay div. How can I have the fadeOutScale animation disappear the div to where the user is currently at on the page?

Comment: Please add a http://jsbin.com of the problem.

Comment: It sounds like maybe .overlay is getting stretched across your whole document and not just across the viewport.